# PHP Update session values after form submit

Tags: php, session

I have a form with a textbox that requires a date value (date1).  When date1 is updated and submitted (posts to same page), it updates the session value with no issues but doesn't update date2 - Explained below.

When date1 is updated date2 doesn't update.  Date2 will get a value by adding 30 days to date1.

**In summary:** **Date1** - session variable gets updated after submitting the form.  **Date2** - session variable does not get updated after submitting the form.  BUT both date1 & date2 updates in the database.

I have spent days trying to find the issue.  I figured out how to get date1 to update the session variable but date2 I cannot figure it out.

Note: I echo the session variable.  That's how I know it's not updating on the page. The echo isn't in the code below.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$memberid = $_SESSION['memberid'];  
$date1 = $_POST['date1'];
$date2 = $_SESSION['date2'];    

if(empty($_POST['date1'])){
$errordate1[] = 'Select a Date';
$_SESSION['date1'];

} else {

echo $_SESSION['date1'] = $_POST['date1'];

}


if(empty($_POST['date2'])){

$_SESSION['date2'];

} else {

echo $_SESSION['date2'] = $_POST['date2'];

}



if(!isset($errordate1)){

$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date1']));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1 . " +30 days"));
echo $date2; // I do not get the updated date.  
//die($date2); // if I uncomment this line I get the updated value for date2.


    try {

    $_SESSION['date2'] = $_POST['date2'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE theDates SET date1 = :date1, date2 = :date2, WHERE 
memberid=:memberid');
    $stmt->execute(array(':date1'=>$date1, ':date2'=>$date2, ':memberid'=>$memberid));

    header('Location: profile.php');
    exit;

     } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $errordate1[] = $e->getMessage();
     }

    }

    }
```

HTML -  I added a hidden value for date2 for testing.  Thought I would try it and see what happens to trying to get something to work.

```
<form method="post" action="prof.php">
<input name="date1" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($errordate1)){ echo $_POST['date1']; } ?>" />
<input name="date2" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['date2']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Has the session been started for all files using sessions? If not; do. It's required. Error reporting will tell you http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: did you call `session_start()` EVERYWHERE you use session data, BEFORE you use the session data? I'm guessing not...

Comment: ...just you watch and have them come back and say *"Yes it has"*.

Comment: If session_start() wasn't there how would date1 update?   I would think you would be smarter than that.  But here's the answer for you ... yes session_start() does exist.  Thought Fred ii would know that also.

Comment: see what I said @MarcB ? ^ - knew it. As per comment *numero tre*.

Comment: @user5310505 The ones with sharper teeth would've jumped on that faster than a kid on Smarties and feasted royally, what with the code you posted minus the *you know what*. ;-)

Comment: Fred, Why do you continually bother people?  If you haven't a clue what the issues are, move on.  You do this type of aggravating all the time.  I understand you're probably bored with your life.  The issue is other people are trying to accomplish something on a daily basis.  I can go to any forum ask the same question, get an answer, and so can millions of other people.  But some people pick StackOverflow and then are forced to put up with your childish antics.  Don't you think it's time to go somewhere else or grow up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a way to get this to work rather than relying on a bunch of kids. The whole time during the process of changing the code I used:

```
$_SESSION['date2'] = $_POST['date2'];
```

But that was wrong.  Instead it's:

```
$_POST['date2'] = $date2;
```

The code:

```
if(!isset($errordate1)){

    $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date1']));
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1 . " +30 days"));

    if(isset($_POST['date2'])) { 
       $_POST['date2'] = $date2; 

       }

    }
```